# tmux prints "1;2c" whenever I start it or re-attach to a session in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, tmux

If I run `tmux` from my cygwin bash shell it prints `1;2c` on my prompt after tmux launches. If I attach to a session I had open earlier using `tmux attach-session` it does the same thing. If I had vim open in that session it will act as if I had typed `1;2c` in vim.

I made my `.bashrc` empty so I know it's being caused by tmux, not my bash settings.

[Here is my .tmux.conf](https://github.com/positron/dotfiles/blob/master/.tmux.conf)

Comment: How did you install tmux in cygwin?

Comment: You can install it from source if you install libevent (and maybe ncurses?) from source too. Just google for instructions and you'll find several posts. The change happened after 1.8 so you need the latest trunk from sourceforge.

Comment: `tmux 1.9a1` is now available as a pre-built package in Cygwin. However, this problem is still present using the latest `libevent 2.0.21`. This SE question has been linked in the cygwin mailing list. Hopefully the issue will be solved soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There must be a race condition in tmux on cygwin, because changing `escape-time` from 0 to 1 fixes it for me *most of the time*.

For values above 50ms this issue never appears again.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the same problem. It's all about /dev/pts/ permission

Add your user to the tty group with the command  :

```
sudo usermod -a -G tty escaper
```

And then change permissions:

```
sudo chmod 730 /dev/pts
```

or whatever you want but with group writing perm.

Also if you get this problem after make chroot and mount /dev then you can mount dev/pts. So like this :

```
sudo mount --bind /dev/ /home/jail/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts/ /home/jail/dev/pts
```

Comment: As the question is about running tmux in Cygwin (on Windows), that is unlikely to help.